# QGIS Raster Merge - Change in the band values problem

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, merge

I have two raster files and I want to merge them in QGIS. The first raster has values between 0 to 8627 and the second one has 0 to 9118. However, when I do it with the Merge tool (in GDAL/raster miscellaneous) new raster's values are between 0 to 9,260. Somehow, it is rescaled or some raster values are combined. When I checked the map, only one raster is rescaled but the other one stayed as original.

Do you have any suggestions?
[image: here is the tools parameters]

Comment: I dont change any parameters actually. I have added an image to the question about parameters.

Comment: If you are just looking at the min/max values in layer legends in the QGIS Layers tab, your original max values (8627 and 9118) are likely estimated, not actual max.

Comment: Oh yes, I change them via 

Symbology>Min Max Values Settings>Accuracy>Actual(slower)

So there was no problem, just the max min values were poorly estimated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, QGIS shows *estimated* min and max values in the layer legend (faster). To see the actual values, in the raster layer properties, symbology tab, change "Accuracy" from "Estimate (faster)" to "Actual (slower)".

[image]